# Missing dependencies while trying to upload file with jersey

Tags: java, web-services, rest, jersey, multipartform-data

I am trying to develop an application to upload a file with Jersey but i get errors on dependencies. I have checked also other posts but I did not find any solution.

Below is the error:

```
SEVERE: The following errors and warnings have been detected with resource and/or provider classes:
  SEVERE: Missing dependency for method public javax.ws.rs.core.Response Upload.server.uploadFile(java.io.InputStream,com.sun.jersey.core.header.FormDataContentDisposition) at parameter at index 0
  SEVERE: Missing dependency for method public javax.ws.rs.core.Response Upload.server.uploadFile(java.io.InputStream,com.sun.jersey.core.header.FormDataContentDisposition) at parameter at index 1
  SEVERE: Method, public javax.ws.rs.core.Response Upload.server.uploadFile(java.io.InputStream,com.sun.jersey.core.header.FormDataContentDisposition), annotated with POST of resource, class Upload.server, is not recognized as valid resource method.
Jun 27, 2014 12:37:16 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
```

Here is my code:

```
package Upload;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;

import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

import com.sun.jersey.core.header.FormDataContentDisposition;
import com.sun.jersey.multipart.FormDataParam;


@Path("/file")
public class server {
    @POST
    @Path("/upload")
    @Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
    public Response uploadFile(
        @FormDataParam("file") InputStream uploadedInputStream,
        @FormDataParam("file") FormDataContentDisposition fileDetail) {

        String uploadedFileLocation = "c://" + fileDetail.getFileName();

        writeToFile(uploadedInputStream, uploadedFileLocation);

        String output = "File uploaded to : " + uploadedFileLocation;

        return Response.status(200).entity(output).build(); 
    }

    private void writeToFile(InputStream uploadedInputStream, String uploadedFileLocation) {

        try {
            OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File(uploadedFileLocation));
            int read = 0;
            byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];

            out = new FileOutputStream(new File(uploadedFileLocation));
            while ((read = uploadedInputStream.read(bytes)) != -1) {
                out.write(bytes, 0, read);
            }
            out.flush();
            out.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
    } 
}
```

Below is an image of my Jars

[image]

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Similar question asked & have answer 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24445901/file-upload-services-using-jersey-in-tomcat-without-maven/24448770#24448770

Comment: It WORKED, thank you man! I will also give a vote to the other answer